# Limitation of number of sum() in a query in MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql

I recently installed MySQL 8 and found out that some queries no longer run. The error is:

`SQL Error (1022): Can't write; duplicate key in table 'C:\WINDOWS\SERVIC~1\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\#sql2db8_13_26'`

There were no issues with MySQL 5.7 or older versions.

All my research in forums showed that this usually happens in case of foreign keys and constraints. I don't have any, just Primary key and 2 indexes.

My query produces 843 columns with KPIs all of which are aggregated with sum(). What made me impression is that if I remove approx 2/3 of the query content the query runs normally without any errors. Also if I remove group by or all of sums there are no issues either.

So I am wondering whether there is any new limatitaion of number of aggregate operators in MySQL 8.0.

A simplified example of my query is below. Table is running MyISAM.

```
select Time,eNodeB,
round((sum(`L.E-RAB.SuccEst.QCI.1`)/sum(`L.E-RAB.AttEst.QCI.1`))*100,3) as RAB_Est_SR,
sum(`L.E-RAB.AttEst.QCI.1`) as RAB_Est_att,
...
from h_cell
where enodeb='10006' and time>='2018-01-01'
group by time
```

Answer (score 1):

No! there is no limitation. As your error message said, you have duplicate key for grouping. This means your usage of GROUP BY is not true! You must use every column (Except scalar ones) in front of select in GROUP clause.
So, you must change your query to:

```
select Time,eNodeB,
round((sum(`L.E-RAB.SuccEst.QCI.1`)/sum(`L.E-RAB.AttEst.QCI.1`))*100,3) as RAB_Est_SR,
sum(`L.E-RAB.AttEst.QCI.1`) as RAB_Est_att,
...
from h_cell
where enodeb='10006' and time>='2018-01-01'
group by time,eNodeB
```